# Copy table in HBase from Java

Tags: java, hbase, nosql

I want to copy data from one HBase table to another using Java APIs, but not able to find one. Is there any Java API to do the same?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following is not by far the most optimized way - but from the tone of the question it seems performance is not the critical factor here.

First, you need to set up your HBaseConfiguration and your input / output tables:

Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();

HTable inputTable = new HTable(config, "input_table");
HTable outputTable = new HTable(config, "output_table");

What you want is a "Scan", which allows a range scan to be performed.  You need to define the query parameters, by adding columns to a Scan object.

```
Scan scan = new Scan(Bytes.toBytes("smith-"));
scan.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("personal"), Bytes.toBytes("givenName"));
scan.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("contactinfo"), Bytes.toBytes("email"));
scan.setFilter(new PageFilter(25));
```

Now you are ready to invoke the scan object and retrieve results:

```
ResultScanner scanner = inputTable.getScanner(scan);
for (Result result : scanner) {
    putToOutputTable(result);
}
```

Now to save to the second table, you will either do Put's within the for loop, or aggregate the results into a List/Array or similar for a bulk put.

```
protected void putToOutputTable(Result result) {

    // Retrieve the Map of families to their most recent qualifiers and values.

    NavigableMap<byte[],NavigableMap<byte[],byte[]>>  map = result.getNoVersionMap();

    for (  // iterate through the family/values map entries for this result ) {
    // Convert the result to the row key and the column values here ..
    // specifically set the rowKey, colFamily, colQualifier, and colValue(s)

    Put p = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(rowKey));

    // To set the value you'd like to update in the row 'myLittleRow',
    // specify the column family, column qualifier, and value of the table
    // cell you'd like to update. The column family must already exist
    // in your table schema. The qualifier can be anything.
    // All must be specified as byte arrays as hbase is all about byte
    // arrays. Lets pretend the table 'myLittleHBaseTable' was created
    // with a family 'myLittleFamily'.
    p.add(Bytes.toBytes(colFamily), Bytes.toBytes(colQualifier),
    Bytes.toBytes(colValue));
 }
 table.put(p);
```

}

If instead you want a more scalable version, take a look at how to use map/reduce to read from input hdfs files / write to output hbase tables here: [Hbase Map/Reduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061854/hadoop-writing-to-hbase-directly-from-the-mapper)